# Python: TypeError thrown when parsing digits from an integer

Tags: python

Code:

```
two_digit_number = input()
yellow = int(two_digit_number)
print(type(yellow))
print(str(yellow[1]))
```

Error:

```
<class 'int'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(str(yellow[1]))
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

**What I am expecting?**
If the input is 34, the output should be 7; as the sum of 3 + 4.

Comment: You can use indexing on strings -  `'34'[1]` would be fine, `34[1]` is not, as you cannot index integers.

Comment: You want to use the original string `print(two_digit_number[1])`

Comment: In your example, change this: `print(str(yellow[1]))` to this: `print(str(yellow)[1])`. Or, just don't convert the input to an int.  Just use `yellow = input()`, as the `input` function returns a string.  Or, do use integers and use `n % 10` iteratively to 'peel off' the digits.

Answer (score 0):

this line print(str(yellow[1])) is trying to access the number by it's index but that functionality is only present in a string, since you've converted the input to an int here yellow = int(two_digit_number) use this variable instead two_digit_number[1]

Answer (score 0):

For increased efficiency, you can use pure math to solve this one, and *forget expensive string manipulation*. The key is using [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) to essentially 'peel' off the single digits to be added.

For example:

```
sum_ = 0
n = int(input('Enter a number: '))

while n > 0:
    # Accumulate the sum for each 'ones' digit.
    sum_ += n % 10
    # Divide N by 10 to 'strip off' the accumulated digit.
    n //= 10

print(f'Answer: {sum_}')
```

Answer (score -1):

your code doing this

```
two_digit_number = input() # taking user input, string type
yellow = int(two_digit_number) # converting user input to int type
print(type(yellow)) # printing type of the variable yellow
print(str(yellow[1])) # indexing the integer, which is throwing error
```

if you want to get sum of all the digit for your input, then you need to iterate through each digit, convert individual digit to int type and then add them together

below code does this

```
two_digit_number = input()
digit_sum = 0 
for digit in two_digit_number:
    if digit.isdigit():
        digit_sum += int(digit)
    else:
        raise TypeError(f"expecting {digit} to be int type, found {type(digt)}")
print(digit_sum)
```